# TitleCase In Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, title-case

I'm currently trying to find an easy way to convert a Visual (Managed) C++ string to title case.
In VB.NET, you can use either:

```
StrConv(sampleString, vbProperCase)
```

or

```
sampleString = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sampleString)
```

In C# you use:

```
sampleString = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sampleString)
```

How do I do it in Visual C++? Is it something similar that I just can't seem to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation on [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) it has examples for Managed C++

Comment: Check your language filter on the top of the page.  You might have MSDN set to only show you C# code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about managed C++, you can use the same functions as in C#/VB.Net.

If you mean native C++, then:

1. Pretty certain there's nothing of the sort in the language itself.
2. AFAIK not in the Win32 API as well.
3. Your best hope then is to find such a function in some library (I personally can't think of one).

Comment: It is managed, but for some reason I intellisense only gives me a "get" function once I use "System::Globalization::CultureInfo::CurrentUICulture"

Comment: Found the answer at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(VS.71).aspx

They are the same, but it would seem my poor grasp of the language prevented me from getting it to work.